# Using DC-DC converter with input voltage same the specified output voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a circuit board with a full bridge PWM motor control. The full bridge component (HIP4081A) needs 12VDC input voltage but can be used to switch 24VDC voltage motors. I want to use the same circuit board for both 12VDC and 24VDC systems.

I use a 24-to-12V DC-DC converter (tsr 0.5-2412) to get 12VDC to the full bridge. This works fine when the input voltage is 24V but when input voltage is 12VDC the DC-DC component (tsr 0.5-2412) gets an input voltage that is lower than specified minimum input voltage which is 15VDC.

When the input voltage to the 24-to-12V DC-DC converter (tsr 0.5-2412) is 12V the output will be about 1V lower. Is it ok to use the DC-DC converter outside the specified input range or is there a risk that I destroy the dc-dc converter?

Is it a good idea to short circuit the input and output of the DC-DC converter e.q via MOSFET when voltage drops below 15V? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: *Is it ok to use the DC-DC converter outside the specified input range* You should not exceed the maximum ratings. If a device can handle more than what is "printed on the box" then why would they not print the higher number because that would be "better". Also **draw a schematic** of your circuit proposal.

Comment: There are converters made for this job called buck-boost convertors which can step up, step down, or simply transfer power as required. So ... why not use the right tool for the job?

Comment: To add to @BrianDrummond's comment, it also seems like very wide input range buck-boost converter modules are becoming more common than they used to be. You may be able to find a pre-built module from Murata, Recom, or another reputable power supply company for not that much money.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think a buck-boost converter is what I'm looking for. In some datasheets I found the term "4:1 input range" which I think is what I need. See example https://www.tracopower.com/products/ten6.pdf